# How to deal with an uneven bathroom floor?

Tags: cleaning, water, bathroom

Because of [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9311/compensating-for-uneven-flooring-in-house) I remembered about when I was still renting and the bathroom (aka: comfort room/lavatory/washroom/etc) in my apartment is not level and it causes the water to go to the side where there's no drainage.

**Question:** How do I deal with it permanently?

Things I've tried:

1. Ask my landlord to fix it, unfortunately she said that it is impossible, because my bathroom tiles already.
2. I bought a rubber rug which helps my feet to avoid my feet becoming wet whenever I will use the bathroom.
3. Every time I take a bath I sweep and clean the excess water (Hassle!)

Comment: A comfort room? Oh, in Philippines we just say it C.R. Sorry.

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=comfort%20room)

Comment: You should ask this on [DIY/Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com). Major repairs and permanent remediation are outside the purview of this site.

Answer (score 1):

When fixing the room is out of the question, as you suggest, you have two options left in my book:

- Reduce the water spill
- Contain spill water as good as possible

### Reducing water spill

It goes without saying that you should try not to splash water around, but this should go into the sink, and not onto the floor. That leaves three common sources: 1) Shower, 2) Washing machine and possibly 3) clothes drying.

Regarding the washing machine if you don't have it already, please get a hose so that you can redirect the spill water into the toilet bowl, sink or closer to the drain.

If possible avoid clothes drying in the bathroom, or ensure that there is good ventilation which help moist get out of the bathroom instead of accumulating and forming droplets. Avoid hanging up dripping clothes by either wringing them or giving them an extra run through the sentrifuge.

### Containing spill water

For the shower, which hopefully is close to the drain, you have two different paths to go. You could opt for buying yourself out of the problem by acquiring a shower cabinet, which contains all the water and you can control the spill water to go into the drain.

The other path, is to use shower curtains to reduce the wet area, and in addition you can add a shower edge guard just outside of the shower curtains.

Some alternative options for shower edge guard:

- The best, when not using a shower cabinet, would be a low bricked edge, but this would change the physical bathroom so is most likely not a viable option whilst renting
- Lists of various materials can also be used, i.e. rubber or plastic guards
- In a pinch, you can even use a long wet towel which you roll together to form the guard preventing the water from extending into the wrong side of the bath

Finally you need to take care when drying your self to stay in the wet area, where the drain is, and avoid dragging water all over. So before taking the bath, make sure that you have the necessary stuff readily available, so you don't have to cross the bathroom to get stuff like a dry towel.